# Prove that p^3 - 1 is a composite number given P > 2

Tags: proof

In order to prove a number composite I have to prove that p^3 - 1 = ab
With a and b not being 1 and itself. Its given that p > 2.

I factor it out with differences of squares 
p^3 - 1 => (p - 1)(p^2 + p + 1)

And I don't really know what to do next. How do I involve p > 2 into the proof.

Comment: Isn't it utterly trivial that if `p>2` then `p-1` is neither 1 nor `p^3 - 1`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Would fit on [math.se].

Comment: You already showed that for most p it is composite by expressing it as the product of two terms. The only problem case as John Coleman points out is that if p = 2 then it degenerates to 1 times p^2 + p + 1

Comment: okay please close this question sorry I didn't realize I was in coding

Answer (score 2):

Its a composite number only if its a product of two numbers a and b both of which are greater than 1. If p = 2, then a would be 1.

```
If (p > 2) - then 
(p - 1) > 1 and 
(p^2 + p + 1) > 1.
```

Comment: p has to be greater than 2

Comment: Yes, that's the point. p has to be greater than 2 for p-1 to be greater than 1. p^2 + p + 1 is always greater than 1 for p>2.

Comment: If p > 2 - then (p - 1) > 1 and (p^2 + p + 1) > 1.

Comment: okay I understand thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Just use induction.

Base case p=3, p**3-1 = 8.

Inductive case: use your factorization.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard it's close enough. You get the idea.